# How to build SOCI with PostgreSQL?

Tags: c++, postgresql, soci

I'm trying to build the SOCI library to run with PostgreSQL. I followed these steps:

- Install PostgreSQL in Ubutu 15.10
- Download SOCI source code
- Extract SOCI code

I then run the following commands:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DWITH_BOOST=OFF -DWITH_POSTGRESQL=ON -DPOSTGRESQL_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/pgsql/include -DPOSTGRESQL_LIBRARIES=/usr/local/pgsql/lib ../soci
```

At this point, CMake gave the following warnings:

```
WARNING: Target "soci_postgresql" requests linking to directory "/usr/local/pgsql/lib".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "soci_postgresql_static" requests linking to directory "/usr/local/pgsql/lib".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "soci_postgresql_test" requests linking to directory "/usr/local/pgsql/lib".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "soci_postgresql_test" requests linking to directory "/usr/local/pgsql/lib".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "soci_postgresql_test_static" requests linking to directory "/usr/local/pgsql/lib".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "soci_postgresql_test_static" requests linking to directory "/usr/local/pgsql/lib".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
```

Persisting with the build, I then ran `make`, which fails with the following error:

```
[ 98%] Building CXX object tests/postgresql/CMakeFiles/soci_postgresql_test.dir/test-postgresql.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/soci_postgresql_test
../../lib/libsoci_postgresql.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `PQresultStatus'
../../lib/libsoci_postgresql.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `PQgetvalue'
../../lib/libsoci_postgresql.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `PQclear'
../../lib/libsoci_postgresql.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `PQserverVersion'
../../lib/libsoci_postgresql.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `PQresultErrorMessage'
../../lib/libsoci_postgresql.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `PQexec'
../../lib/libsoci_postgresql.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `lo_lseek'
../../lib/libsoci_postgresql.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `PQfsize'
../../lib/libsoci_postgresql.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `PQgetisnull'
../../lib/libsoci_postgresql.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `PQerrorMessage'
../../lib/libsoci_postgresql.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `lo_open'
../../lib/libsoci_postgresql.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `PQexecPrepared'
../../lib/libsoci_postgresql.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `PQftype'
../../lib/libsoci_postgresql.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `lo_close'
../../lib/libsoci_postgresql.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `PQexecParams'
../../lib/libsoci_postgresql.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `PQfname'
../../lib/libsoci_postgresql.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `PQconnectdb'
../../lib/libsoci_postgresql.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `PQstatus'
../../lib/libsoci_postgresql.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `PQntuples'
../../lib/libsoci_postgresql.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `PQresultErrorField'
../../lib/libsoci_postgresql.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `PQfformat'
../../lib/libsoci_postgresql.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `lo_read'
../../lib/libsoci_postgresql.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `PQfinish'
../../lib/libsoci_postgresql.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `PQprepare'
../../lib/libsoci_postgresql.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `lo_write'
../../lib/libsoci_postgresql.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `PQcmdTuples'
../../lib/libsoci_postgresql.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `PQnfields'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
tests/postgresql/CMakeFiles/soci_postgresql_test.dir/build.make:89: recipe for target 'bin/soci_postgresql_test' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/soci_postgresql_test] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:609: recipe for target 'tests/postgresql/CMakeFiles/soci_postgresql_test.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [tests/postgresql/CMakeFiles/soci_postgresql_test.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any idea what the cause of the CMake warnings and build error might be?

Answer (score 2):

Try to call cmake with slightly different options

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DWITH_BOOST=OFF -DWITH_POSTGRESQL=ON \
  -DPOSTGRESQL_INCLUDE_DIR:STRING="/usr/local/pgsql/include" \
  -DPOSTGRESQL_LIBRARIES:STRING="/usr/local/pgsql/lib" ../soci
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the right answer from the github, [here is link](https://github.com/SOCI/soci/issues/543#issuecomment-313305435).
The following reply is largely taken from there, but repeated here for convenience (with cleanup and clarification):

`-DPOSTGRESQL_LIBRARIES=/usr/local/psql/lib` should point to the libraries, not directories.

This is what the following warning already highlights:

> WARNING: Target "soci_postgresql" requests linking to directory
>   "/usr/local/postgresql/lib"

Try the following command instead (you may need to delete your `CMakeCache.txt` from the build directory first as well):

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DWITH_BOOST=OFF -DWITH_POSTGRESQL=ON ../soci
```

On Linux systems where `"postgresql-devel.x86_64 : PostgreSQL development header files and libraries"` is installed, this command should be enough.